# tsParticles particles spawner

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles, particles.js

I've seen [this sample](https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/wvKKXXa) of [`tsParticles`](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles) but I can't make it work.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bsj30hwf/